# Cufon Fonts on Subdomains

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, cufon

I have this WordPress theme installed. it works perfectly on a domain. When I installed the theme on a sub domain, some of the fonts fail to work. I got to discover they're cufon fonts and I'm a newbie to such. How can I make them work on the sub domain? My site is [here](http://zikiza.com/) and my subdomain site is [here](http://definition.zikiza.com/) .Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be the Cufon font itself, when you generate the Cufon js you can tie the code to a specific domain. Regenerate the font and remove the domain restriction or else create multiple versions tied to specific subdomains.